# Upgrading Graphics Chip on Notebook

Tags: ati, dual-boot, windows-7

I know this isn't exactly a Ubuntu question but in my experience the Ubuntu community has been the best and most helpful for anything vaguely computer related. I am running a dual-boot 64-bit Windows 7 Pro (I suck at using wine and my windows partition is used only for games) and Ubuntu 64-bit 11.04 (haven't upgraded to O.O. Yet) on an HP ProBook 4520s using an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 graphics card, and was wondering if it is possible to upgrade this card, and if so what the best card to upgrade too would be?

Comment: ... its an interesting question and IMHO I doubt you can easily change chips in modern notebooks since they are either integrated or soldered on the motherboard...  that said - its probably still off-topic.  Possibly you need to post this on a hardware related StackExchange website (if such a forum exists).

Comment: Upgrading the graphics card on a **laptop**? Are you serious?  Usually the graphics card is soldered in.

Comment: I only recently got into the hardware aspect of computers, ive been a software guy for a while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The few models I know, where you can actually upgrade the video cards are usually really high-end. I have tried to find details on your machine, but have not found anything indicating yours can. I have only read that in some efforts to save money, some OEM's shipped your HD 5470 with DDR3 instead of DDR5 memory which could lead to poorer performance. [It supports GDDR5, but due to cost savings, the card may often be outfitted with slower DDR3 memory.](http://www.notebookcheck.net/ATI-Mobility-Radeon-HD-5470.23698.0.html)

Comment: mine is DDR3, so i can upgrade to DDR5? i was under the impression that DDR3 and DDR5 slots were incompatible, forward or backwards. but considering this was a $1100 notebook purchased last year i was hoping that there was a possibility of having the Graphics chip not soldered, because it is a real ATI Radeon chip not an integrated Intel HD chip. I was wondering because I play The Witcher 2 and have some minor performance problems with everything absolutely low-spec even though the system requirements for middle specs are exceeded by my computer.